# Robot Framework - Execute Sql Script Keyword from Data Library with PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7, robotframework, psycopg2

I'm trying to `INSERT` data into a table from a database at PostgreSQL using robot framework (`Database Library`) in order to accomplish it

There is a column in an Excel File, which already has the SQL Script, and my ideia is for each row in that column, inserts the information into the Database.

Please find below the script:

```
*** Settings ***
Library           SeleniumLibrary
Library           ExcelLibrary
Library           Database Library

*** Test Cases ***
Update DB
Connect To Database    psycopg2    ${DBNAME}    ${USER_NAME}    ${PASSWORD}    localhost    5432
Open Excel    D:\\RPA\\Demo\\FIPEExcelDone.xls
@{sqlc}=    Get Column Values    Tabela    6
@{query}=    Query    select * from fipe_price
FOR    ${VAR4}    IN ZIP    ${sqlc}
    Run Keyword If    "${VAR4}[1]" == "SQL"    Continue For Loop
    LOG    ${VAR4}[1]
    Execute Sql Script    ${VAR4}[1]
END
```

Everything is working, however, when the code executes the keyword `Execute Sql Script`, an error appears

`IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u"INSERT INTO fipe_price (mes_pe....`

In order to check if the problem could be on the SQL Script, I have manually inserted into Postgre the SQL Code from the Excel File and the code has worked fine, therefore, I don´t understand when I try to run from the robot framework if does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyword you've used [`Execute Sql Script`](https://franz-see.github.io/Robotframework-Database-Library/api/0.6/DatabaseLibrary.html#Execute%20Sql%20Script) expects you to pass a file, which it'll open & execute all statements in it.
What you are looking for is [`Execute Sql String`](https://franz-see.github.io/Robotframework-Database-Library/api/0.6/DatabaseLibrary.html#Execute%20Sql%20String) - the string passed as an argument is executed directly on the server.